# Host multiple CMSs at the same domain.

Tags: linux, centos, vps, cms, owncloud

Currently I have a VPS hosting ownCloud. I have added a domain name to the server, so now it is (an example) example.com instead of an IP. I was wondering if (and how) I could add another CMS at the same domain, like example.com/files. I do not have a control panel, just root access to a Linux server runnning Centos 6 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, you can add additional CMS at subdirectories with wget utility.

wget retrieves files from World Wide Web (WWW) using widely used protocols like HTTP, HTTPS and FTP. You will just have to create directories through shell or midnight commander utility, navigate to specific directory where you want to download the CMS and fire wget command.

As an alternative, you can host multiple websites on single IP address using Apache Virtual Hosts. The sites display different information to the visitors, depending on with which the users accessed the site.There is no limit to the number of virtual hosts that can be added to a VPS. Here is good guide on how you can Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on CentOS 6

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-6

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Apache as your webserver, you'll need to add [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) entries for each domain name you want to serve.